# Custom converter for textbox

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs, ssjs

Let me put the question in other words so, it may help remove it as a duplicate,
Is there a way to to use Xpages custom converter to display URL in text box as a hyperlink.[image]

Comment: it has to "behave" like a link or it just needs to look like a link? i mean, what should happen if you click it?

Comment: @Rayon please unmark this as a duplicate. It's not. This is about a custom converter in XPages, not a JavaScript solution. The JavaScript solution is inadvisable as it would require duplication of code across applications and within application. XPages best practice is to use a custom converter coded in Java / SSJS or ideally is an OSGi plugin and applied to components via a theme.

Comment: it should behave like a link

Comment: @Rayon - as Paul Withers said - this is not a duplicate question.  This has nothing to do with the question you linked to as this is NOT a JavaScript question.  This is a question on XPages technology and server side rendering.

Comment: hope if duplicate is not removed from here will get some hint on notesin9.com or http://www.intec.co.uk/

Comment: I sent a note to the moderators to try and remove the duplicate flag.  If not you can always re-ask and just use xpages tags and not the javascript tag because that person doesn't have a clue about what you're trying to do.  the only answer I can give you us "custom renderer". This was featured on NotesIn9 156 and 174 as well as also 63 an 64 I believe.  I'd start with the more recent shows.

Comment: Hi @All, My sincere apologies guys. I have voted to re-open this question..

Comment: I added my vote to re-open, and I think that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

No, a converter converts data types... you would need a custom renderer to write out the needed anchor tags around your link.

What type of control are you using? If a `<text>` control (computed field) you can specify it as html for the content type and wrap your value you are getting from somewhere around the appropriate `<a>` tags.